# Input string was not in a correct format in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, .net-core, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I create a project base MAUI Microsoft for Android app,
I run it on the emulator and I don't have any problem, but when I wrote something in the project I get this error, and I can't find any answer for that.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiApp3.Models"
             x:Class="MauiApp3.MainPage">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,auto"
          ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
        <CollectionView>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{Type models:UserModel}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding UserName}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Text="Get Users" Margin="8"
                    FontSize="25"></Button>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

> ERROR -------------------
> Input string was not in a correct format

I try to create a MAUI app for Android phone

Comment: `x:DataType="{Type models:UserModel}"` - why do you have `Type` in this expression?

Comment: I use this for set DataType that I used in this collection

Comment: THAAAAAAAAAAANKS my friend, You hint to the correct statement, I have to use  <<<   <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:UserModel}" >>>  ,and solve my problem ,You are awesome

Answer (score 1):

this

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="{Type models:UserModel}">
```

should be

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:UserModel">
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings)

Comment: I get error with change,

Comment: see my edit, the `{}` are not needed